# Ubuntu 20.04 ClipGrab hangs when loading information about the video

Tags: software-installation, python, video, youtube-dl

I'm having issues with ClipGrab getting stuck on "Please wait while ClipGrab is loading information about the video ..." every time I try to download a video. I installed clipgrab from source and I also tried this [solution](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=336110) to use the .AppImage instead. It doesn't work either way. I'm not sure what's causing the problem here. Is it something related to youtube-dl? Would appreciate any troubleshooting tips/help with this, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while to figure out, but I found the solution at least in my particular case.
When checking my python version I get this:

```
$python --version

Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

I know i have python2 and python3 installed, but it's not showing up in `/usr/bin/python`
After some searching I figured out the issue. ClipGrab is expecting python to be in that path, but it's not there.

Solution:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python2
sudo apt update
```

This will install the package `python-is-python2` and there's a `python-is-python3` as well. You decide which one you need, but for me the first option worked. ClipGrab is now working for me. The solution was to get a link setup `/usr/bin/python -> python2` which is what that package does. Anyway I hope this helps anyone that builds from source.

For more details on the package type `sudo apt show python-is-python2` in cli.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the youtube-dl on Ubuntu derivates are not updated as often as they should.

I've written another (simpler) GUI for youtube-dl, that uses the latest youtube-dl available:

[image]

In case you are interested, look [here](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader)

Else you could uninstall youtube-dl with `apt` and install the actual one using this [script](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader/blob/master/build/installYoutube-dl.sh)